# iTunes Connect: Dutch Localizations

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've developed an application which natively supports the English, German and Dutch language. Now I am about to submit the app into iTunes Connect, but I think I might have a problem here.

I have read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide and it states that Dutch is supported as an App Store Localization. However, when I go to my application in iTunes Connect and select the "Localizations" option, I can't add Dutch as a language. The first time you add a language, it says "If you want to create a localization in a language other than your default language, click Add New Language". What is the "default language" here? Is it English or might it be Dutch, therefore Dutch not showing up as a language to add..?

Could somebody help me out of this. Would be much appreciated :-)

Greetings,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which language is configured as the default for your app in iTunes Connect (this part of the interface was changed recently I think).

- Log in to iTunes Connect and select Manage Your Applications
- Navigate to your app and click on the Current Version ("View Details").
- Under App Localizations it will state the default language for this app.

If this is not Dutch, you should indeed be able to add it on the same page.

Comment: Yep, I saw it was. However, I already had sent in the app and it has been approved, so I can't edit the texts and stuff, but I was able to change the default language using the new "new interface". Thanks for your answer!